# Vector Display with Square Brackets

Tags: matlab

Is there a way in MatLab to display a vector with brackets?

My code is simply `display(err.')`
and the output is:

```
ans =

   1.0e-09 *

    0.0198
    0.0470
    0.0674
    0.1044
```

I would like to have it display

```
             0.0198
1.0e-09 *    0.0470
             0.0674
             0.1044
```

With square brackets around the column. Is that possible in MATLAB?

Comment: Not with inbuilt functionality.  You can also try to change the 'format'  to e.g. 'format long g'  to just display the numbers without the exponent

Comment: You can try `pretty(sym(err.'))`, but it will convert the numbers to fractions.

Comment: The long format made it better I think, but, it seems I need to just take the result and move it to some other software for a 'report'